# How to rerender with new value in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
this.state={
  value: 'v1',
  newValue: '',
}

componentDidMount = () => {
  let nV = this.state.value + 'received';
  this.setState({
    newValue: nV,
  });
}

tabClick = (val) => {
  this.setState({
    value: val,
  });
}

render () {
  return (
    <Tabs onTabClick={this.tabClick}>
      <Tab val='v2'>
        {this.state.newValue}
      </Tab>
      <Tab val='v3'>
        {this.state.newValue}
      </Tab>
    </Tabs>
  )
}
```

this is an example scenario of a problem i am facing. When the program loads for the first time it shows in the active tab `v1 received`. When i click on different tabs i change state value of `value` and expecting to `componentDidMount` fire up and change `newValue` which shall change the values of each tab. But when i click the tabs nothing happens. Help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Could you share the complete code of this class? I notice a few issues, but first I want to know whether `this.tabClick` was really executed or not.

Comment: yes it was i have checked it by logging :)

Comment: put this inside `tabClick`, before `this.state`: `alert(val)`. Let me know the result.

Comment: dude it does work i have confirmed depending on click it give 'v2' or 'v3' :)

Comment: You shouldn't use `componentDidMount` for this purpose, it's not going to be invoked whenever you changing the tab. why not set the newval inside `thetabClick`?

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set any states in componentWillMount() function  instead componentDidMount().

The former  lifecycle function is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before render() and hence, make it ideal to change your state here.

The latter is best used when you need to invoke functionalities to load data from remote endpoints. componentDidMount() is invoked after the render function and if state is changedin this function the render() function is invoked again.

Reference:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: tabClick is already bonded because of arrow function - look here http://blog.andrewray.me/react-es6-autobinding-and-createclass/ (Solution 4: Fat Arrow Class Methods)

Comment: @KnutHerrmann Thank you very much for this. I've understood better how this keyword works now. I will update my comment accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it this way

```
this.state={
  value: 'v1',
  newValue: 'v1 received',
}  

tabClick = (val) => {
       let nV = val + 'received';

      this.setState({
        value: val,
        newValue: nV
      });
    }
```

Comment: its a similar case of my actual program where i can not do that :)

Comment: @Shockwave set your initial `newValue` to 'v1 recieved' like the updated answer  then that should work as you want.